# Restricting all but one file format to be uploaded

Tags: php, mysql

I'm studying on MySQL & PHP, and for my first production I've started to work on a review panel. You can simply upload your product reviews to the database and browse them later on, directly from the panel, which in this case is a local website.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to rule over every file format on upload, except .pdf! To be more clear: I only want my upload form to accept .pdf files to be uploaded. At the moment it doesn't restrict anything, here is my code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
  {                                      
    $revName = $_POST['revname'];
    $revRating = $_POST['rating'];
    $revRecommend = $_POST['recommend'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp   = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
      $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    rename($tmpName,"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ReviewArchieve\\files\\reviews\\".$fileName);

    include 'include/config.php';
    include 'include/opendb.php';

    $query = "INSERT INTO files (revname, rating, recommend, name, size, type, content)".
    "VALUES ('$revName', '$revRating', '$revRecommend', '$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error());
    include 'include/closedb.php';

    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
  }
?>
```

**Got it working!**

Thanks to the MIME refer, I managed to learn something new, and accomplished my task with a little bit of investigation! It was not the part of code offered in the correct answer, that did not work at all in my case, no matter what I did, but instead, I used this method:

I noticed I have already included the file type.
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

So now I just had to make an **if** from it, like this:

```
if($fileType == 'application/pdf') {
   *** Code to be driven here, same as above on the original code ***
}
else {
   echo "Invalid file, upload interrupted!";
}
```

Comment: Any kind of improvements to this system overall would be highly appreciated too! I know it looks all messy and the file paths are kind of dumb, but I'm still looking for ways to make them more... functionable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
....
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    if (mime_content_type($tmpname) != 'application/pdf') { 
        die("uploaded file not valid");
    }                              
....
```

You have a number of problems here the biggest are:

1. SQL Injection. You must sanitize your user inputs or little bobby tables will visit you. Think about using parametrized queries
2. You should check the file's mimetype. 
   http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php works out the box although is deprecated. You should use fileinfo.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm looking forward to the first case, but for the second, I'm already aware of that it is "application/pdf", but I could use an example of how to put it in there and where exactly.

Comment: something in the line `if (mime_content_type($tmpname) != 'application/pdf') { die("uploaded file not valid"); }`

Comment: Did not get it working directly by this, but that gave me a good lead to the function I was looking for, so thanks, question answered!